# mysql query with group by not receive zero value

Tags: mysql

From my query below I only receive non-zero values. Why?

```
SELECT
    CAST( `start`  AS DATE), COUNT(`msisdn`) 
FROM 
    `master`
WHERE
    `server_no`='105' 
AND CAST( `start`  AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015-08-20'  
AND '2015-08-31' GROUP BY CAST( `start`  AS DATE), `msisdn`   
AND `msisdn` LIKE '+9472%' OR `msisdn` LIKE '9472%';";
```

The first-row value should be zero, but it is not. Why?

Comment: r u getting result by this query?

Comment: ............... `COUNT(msisdn)   
WHEN > 0`

Comment: @Crazy2crack sorry i couldnt be able to put image

Comment: @ZafarMalik  ya it works

Comment: @LuthandoLoot i tried that not work

Comment: @dhanu i mean try to remove `WHEN > 0`

Comment: @LuthandoLoot extreamly sorry i paste wrong query..it worked without only when.but it couldnt give zero value

Comment: please help me for this query..                                                                                                                count(msisdn)     cast(start as date)                                         23/08/2015         12                                                                                                      24/08/2015          14                                                                                                   24/08/2015         17